# How do I display text elsewhere in my webpage in a textarea?

Tags: html, youtube, textarea, embed

I am working on a youtube video embedder that when you copy and paste a link into, it displays the edited link in the text area.

This is all I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
  <input id="videolink" type="text" value="Youtube Video Identification link(The bit at the end) Here" onfocus="this.value==this.defaultValue?  this.value='':null">
  <br />
  <textarea rows="10">
&lt;iframe width="500" height="500" scr="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"&gt; &lt;iframe&gt;
  </textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text I want to display in the textarea is the videolink text line

Comment: "text elsewhere" - like where? Be specific.

Comment: @EandCProducts are you hoping to set the input[value] to be equal to a user defined value? Set from a text area? If so, I can help but please specify what you need.

Comment: You're gonna need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('videolink'),
    val = xmlencode(input.value),
    textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
    textarea = textareas[0];
textarea.value = val;

function xmlencode(string) {
  return string.replace(/\&/g,'&'+'amp;').replace(/</g,'&'+'lt;').replace(/>/g,'&'+'gt;').replace(/\'/g,'&'+'apos;').replace(/\"/g,'&'+'quot;');
}
```

Here's the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kxxb/2/

Comment: I want it also to put in http://www.youtube.com/embed/ in front of the  video link. Note: There is also http://www. at the front and / at the end of the link.

Comment: Like this? `val = '<p>youtube.com/embed/<p>' + val`

Comment: That doesent work for me, I need it to put it in a specific part of the text thats already there, and its not putting anything in the textarea. Is there any way to activate it?

Comment: I sort of changed the code a bit, the new code is in the question. I want it to place it after embed/ of scr in iframe

Comment: That clarifies things. What you need to do is encode the value before you output it into the textarea value. Let me update my answer.